# Data Binding to an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-2.0

I have an XML file structured as follows:

```
<Levels>
  <Level Code="T" Text="Test">
    <SubLevels>
      <SubLevel Type="9" Text="Nine"/>
      <SubLevel Type="8" Text="Eight"/>
      <SubLevel Type="7" Text="Seven"/>
      <SubLevel Type="6" Text="Six"/>
    </SubLevels>
  </Level>
  <Level Code="T2" Text="Test 2">
    <SubLevels>
      <SubLevel Type="1" Text="One"/>
      <SubLevel Type="2" Text="Two"/>
    </SubLevels>
  </Level>
</Levels>
```

What I want is two drop down lists, one linked to /Levels/Level and one to the SubLevels for the selected level.  Currently, I have the main one bound as follows:

```
 <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlLevelInfo" runat="server" DataFile="~/Levels.xml">
 </asp:XmlDataSource>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cboLevelFilter" runat="server" 
                      DataSourceID="XmlLevelInfo" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Code">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

This works fine, but I can’t work out how to link the Sub Levels to the second drop down list.  Is this possible using data binding?

Comment: Maybe set the datacontact of the other dropdown list to the first one with path SelectedItem, and then in the ItemsSource specify the path to children of the datacontext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that the XmlDataSource for your second drop-down would need to have it's XPath varied on SelectedItemChanged of the first.

Such that it's XPath might look like:
`//Level[@Code = '<CODE VALUE FROM SELECTED ITEM>']//SubLevel`

You'd probably also want to initially just bind it with all SubLevels such that the XPath might look like: `//SubLevel`

Then it'll take a little extra effort to AJAX-ify it all for a nice experience... (Don't forget to set AutoPostBack to true on the first drop-down!)